# MySQL is too slow

Tags: mysql

I don't know why mysql is too slow for querying about 39000 records which include inner join with other two tables. I have country, region and city tables as follows:

**tbl_country**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_country` (
    `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `countryName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `iso2` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `iso3` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `countryName` (`countryName`),
     UNIQUE KEY `iso2` (`iso2`),
     UNIQUE KEY `iso3` (`iso3`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=276 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**tbl_country_region**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_country_region` (
   `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `countryId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `region` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `countryId` (`countryId`,`region`),
   CONSTRAINT `tbl_country_region_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`countryId`)              REFERENCES `tbl_country` (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**tbl_country_city**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_country_city` (
   `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `regionId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   `cityType` enum('Kota','Kabupaten') DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `regionId` (`regionId`,`city`,`cityType`),
   KEY `city_index` (`city`),
   CONSTRAINT `tbl_country_city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`regionId`)
   REFERENCES `tbl_country_region` (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT t1.city, t1.cityType, t2.region, t3.countryName
FROM tbl_country_city t1
    INNER JOIN tbl_country_region t2
        ON t2.id = t1.regionId
    INNER JOIN tbl_country t3
        ON t3.id = t2.countryId
 ORDER BY t1.city
```

and it tooks about 1.032s.

I run show **profile** and here are the results:

```
+------------------------------+----------+
| Status                       | Duration |
+------------------------------+----------+
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000710 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000816 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000734 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000717 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000703 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000698 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000715 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000684 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000718 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000706 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000740 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000786 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000795 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000716 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000716 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000757 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000709 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000740 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000714 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000719 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000712 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000724 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000741 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000739 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000774 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000719 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000716 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000724 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000744 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000744 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000703 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000691 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000719 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000720 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000715 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000720 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000943 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000819 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000703 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000732 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000708 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000703 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000702 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000776 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000006 |
| Sending data                 | 0.000442 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 0.018132 |
| end                          | 0.000018 |
| removing tmp table           | 0.392880 |
| end                          | 0.000019 |
| query end                    | 0.000009 |
| closing tables               | 0.000015 |
| freeing items                | 0.000029 |
| logging slow query           | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up                  | 0.000005 |
+------------------------------+----------+
```

I use **explain** command and here are the results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key         | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | index | PRIMARY           | countryName | 386     | NULL       |  275 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | PRIMARY,countryId | countryId   | 2       | nfis.t3.id |    6 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref   | regionId          | regionId    | 2       | nfis.t2.id |   50 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Why is the query so slow?